# Creating a Year-wise Bar Chart Visualization from CSV Data

Tags: python, pandas, visualization, data-analysis, graph-visualization

## Problem:

I'm working on a data visualization project where I want to create a bar chart similar to the one shown in this [image: reference image]. The image is from a story available [here](https://www.chartr.co/stories/2023-07-24-1-barbenheimer-was-just-the-boost).

## My Effort:

I've written Python code using pandas, seaborn, and matplotlib to visualize the data. Here's my code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

box = pd.read_csv("box_office_18_23.csv")

# Data Cleaning
box["overall_gross"] = box["overall_gross"].str.replace("$", "").str.replace(",", "").astype(int)

# Data Analysis
sns.barplot(x='year', y='overall_gross', data=box)
plt.show()
```

## Output:

Here's the output of my code: [image: Output Image]

## Link to Code and Dataset:

I have uploaded my Jupyter Notebook and the relevant dataset (CSV file) to this [Google Drive link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17jnK-sLac4VbTaPkZSwsZuPCJqYae87K?usp=drive_link).

## Issue:

While my code runs without errors, the resulting bar chart doesn't match the desired visualization. I'm looking for guidance on how to modify my code to achieve a similar year-wise bar chart as shown in the reference image.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think the data behind your desired sample graphs is actually per week / per year (or maybe per release/ per year) with only the year legends shown. So lots more data and with no space and bars of the same color, the spikes are the big weekends (or releases).